# system.security.securityexception request failed with ajaxcontroltoolkit html editor

Tags: c#, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asp.net-4.0, html-editor

I use ajaxcontroltoolkit html editor in my asp.net project. It runs on my local computer but when I deploy, it returns system.security.securityexception.

Do you have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[I found the answer in here:](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/clr/thread/b83773f5-dd97-4c7b-aebf-897ade8db684)

It is about ajaxcontroltoolkit.dll

Answer (score 2):

> You can use the [assembly: attribute] mechanism to put an attribute on an assembly. If you have a class project typically this is done in the AssemblyInfo.cs file in the properties folder as seen below. Note that you can do this in any file in your project though.

This is the response I got from Scott Hunter in the AJAX Control Toolkit team. Is this helpful? I am years down the track and still dealing with this problem. Would help if the solution provided from the AJAX team was a little more descriptive. Have no idea how to resolve.

The problem is caused by "ScriptsCombine" - in medium trust environment, the toolkit must not have permission to combine all the scripts and write them to file system.

Follow here too: http://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/26772